# How to tell Postgres to use an index instead of a bitmap scan?

Tags: postgresql

If I add an extra ORDER clause, Postgres does a Bitmap scan, and the performance drops amazingly (4 seconds vs 0.06 milliseconds). The application becomes unusable. However I am only asking it to order a small set of results, which are indexed , by the way.

How should modify my query so Postgres uses the index instead of bitmap scan? Because using the index is what it should do, I have 100 million records in the table.

Slow query, Bitmap scan:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
        valtr_id,
        from_id,
        to_id,
        from_balance,
        to_balance,
        block_num
FROM value_transfer v
WHERE v.block_num<=2435013 AND v.to_id = 22479 
ORDER BY block_num desc,valtr_id desc
LIMIT 1

 Limit  (cost=1235402.27..1235402.27 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=4665.595..4665.596 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1235402.27..1238237.41 rows=1134056 width=32) (actual time=4665.594..4665.594 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: block_num DESC, valtr_id DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on value_transfer v  (cost=21229.61..1229731.99 rows=1134056 width=32) (actual time=268.917..4170.374 rows=1102867 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (to_id = 22479)
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 9412580
               Filter: (block_num <= 2435013)
               Heap Blocks: exact=32392 lossy=132879
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vt_to_id_idx  (cost=0.00..20946.10 rows=1134071 width=0) (actual time=254.870..254.870 rows=1102867 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (to_id = 22479)
 Planning time: 0.290 ms
 Execution time: 4665.634 ms
(13 rows)
```

Now, if I remove just one ORDER condition, the query is orders of magnitude faster.

Without `ORDER by valtr_id DESC` I have the following performance:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
        valtr_id,
        from_id,
        to_id,
        from_balance,
        to_balance,
        block_num
FROM value_transfer v
WHERE v.block_num<=2435013 AND v.to_id = 22479 
ORDER BY block_num desc
LIMIT 1

 Limit  (cost=0.57..2.46 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using idx_2 on value_transfer v  (cost=0.57..2148650.88 rows=1134056 width=32) (actual time=0.027..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((to_id = 22479) AND (block_num <= 2435013))
 Planning time: 0.310 ms
 Execution time: 0.060 ms
(5 rows)
```

How do i tell Postgres to use the INDEX first, and only after that - SORT the results ?

My table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE value_transfer (
    valtr_id            BIGSERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    tx_id               BIGINT          REFERENCES transaction(tx_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    block_id            INT             REFERENCES block(block_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    block_num           INT             NOT NULL,
    from_id             INT             NOT NULL,
    to_id               INT             NOT NULL,
    value               NUMERIC         DEFAULT 0,
    from_balance        NUMERIC         DEFAULT 0,
    to_balance          NUMERIC         DEFAULT 0,
    kind                CHAR            NOT NULL,
    depth               INT             DEFAULT 0,
    error               TEXT            NOT NULL
);
```

I have created lots of different indexes during my tests:

```
      indexname      |                                        indexdef                                         
---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 value_transfer_pkey | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX value_transfer_pkey ON public.value_transfer USING btree (valtr_id)
 vt_block_id_idx     | CREATE INDEX vt_block_id_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (block_id)
 vt_block_num_idx    | CREATE INDEX vt_block_num_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (block_num)
 vt_from_id_idx      | CREATE INDEX vt_from_id_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (from_id)
 vt_to_id_idx        | CREATE INDEX vt_to_id_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (to_id)
 vt_tx_from_idx      | CREATE INDEX vt_tx_from_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (tx_id)
 idx_1               | CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON public.value_transfer USING btree (from_id, block_num DESC)
 idx_2               | CREATE INDEX idx_2 ON public.value_transfer USING btree (to_id, block_num DESC)
 idx_1_rev           | CREATE INDEX idx_1_rev ON public.value_transfer USING btree (block_num DESC, from_id)
 idx_2_rev           | CREATE INDEX idx_2_rev ON public.value_transfer USING btree (block_num DESC, to_id)
 valtr_ordered_idx   | CREATE INDEX valtr_ordered_idx ON public.value_transfer USING btree (valtr_id)
(11 rows)
```

Comment: You need an index on `(block_num, valtr_id)`

Comment: The indexes `vt_block_num_idx`, `vt_from_id_idx` and `vt_to_id_idx` are useless as there are other indexes with those columns as the leading column - you can drop those single column indexes. And `valtr_ordered_idx` is useless because you already have a  unique index on `valtr_id`

Comment: you are so right! thanks. last question, would it be different if I change the index to `(valtr_id,block_num)` ?

Comment: I mean, does the order of the fields in parenthesis should match the ORDER clause in the query?